# Fix segmentation fault caused by accessing stack memory without permission c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stack

I'd like to access stack in c++, but at some point I get segmentation fault  error. Here is my code:

```
ofstream ostream;
ostream.open("stackContents.txt");

const int s = sl.rlim_max;
unsigned char a[s];
for(int i = 0; i<sl.rlim_max;++i){
    if (a[i] == NULL) ostream << endl;
    ostream << a[i];
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2));
    cout << i << endl;
}
ostream.close();
```

Comment: Only the kernel runs in ring 0 while device drivers run in ring 1.

Comment: You either need to modify your kernel or find a vulnerability in your kernel's implementation which allows execution of arbitrary code. It'd be a massive security risk if any kernel intentionally allowed user code to run in ring 0.

Comment: ring0/kernel mode is platform dependent, if you want to do this, you have to do it in a platform specific manner. (Ofcourse, if your goal is to fix a segmentation fault caused by wrong access of stack memory, you are on a very wrong path to "fix" your issue)